# Wrapping an an html anchor tag around an array is causing unexpected results in my React component

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that I use in my react app that generates a random game on the screen.

It's working, but now I'm trying to add some html into the game title.

When I do that, my game titles come up as:

> [object Object]

Here is where I generate a random game:

```
const newGame = () => {
  return {

    title: <a href="#">gameTitleArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * gameTitleArray.length)]</a>,
    type: gameTypeArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * gameTypeArray.length)],
    startDate: getDate(new Date(2019, 0, 1), new Date()),
    endDate: getDate(new Date(2022, 0, 1), new Date()),
  }
}
```

You can see I'm trying to wrap an html anchor tag around the 'title' portion.

Here is how I'm exporting the component:

```
export default function makeGameData(...lens) {
  const makeGameDataLevel = (depth = 0) => {
    const len = lens[depth]
    return range(len).map(d => {
      return {
        ...newGame(),
        subRows: lens[depth + 1] ? makeGameDataLevel(depth + 1) : undefined,
      }
    })
  }

  return makeGameDataLevel()
}
```

Here is an example of the gameTypeArray:

```
const gameTypeArray = ['RPG', 'Western', 'Real-Time Strategy', 'Fantasy', 'First Person Shooter']
```

And an example of gameTitleArray:

```
const gameTitleArray = ['Future Agent','Human Universe','Chase of Resitution','Destroy of Resitution','Days and Glitch','Mayhem and Faith','Dynaworks','Crystalback','Fusionheart','Hellscape']
```

I even tried creating a separate function like this:

```
function gameTitleArrayLink() {
    const gameTitleArray = ['Future Agent','Human Universe','Chase of Resitution','Destroy of Resitution','Days and Glitch','Mayhem and Faith','Dynaworks','Crystalback','Fusionheart','Hellscape']
    const title =  gameTitleArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * gameTitleArray.length)]
    const titleUrl = <a href="#">{title}</a>
    return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: titleUrl }} />
}
```

And then setting the title like this:

```
 title: researchSummaryList()
```

Obviously I'm doing something wrong, but I'm not getting any errors, just the [object Object]

Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping the array value in `{}` to have it treated as an expression:

```js
<a href="#">{gameTitleArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * gameTitleArray.length)]}</a>
```

Comment: I tried that, but I'm still getting the [object Object]

Comment: What is `gameTypeArray`?

Comment: It's just another array but instead of game titles it's game types.

Comment: Ah then there's your problem. You can't render arrays unless they are arrays of react elements. In JavaScript Arrays are Objects. So thats why you see `[object Object]`. You need to reference a specific element that will be a primitive value instead of another array/object.

Comment: It might be helpful if you post an example of the `gameTypeArray` in your question.

Comment: Thanks, I added an example gameTypeArray

Comment: `gameTitleArray` as well. I'm sorry I mixed them up.. Seeing how `makeGameData` may also be insightful

Comment: sorry, I just added it.  Thanks!

Comment: Nothing looks off there. My guess is it has to do with how the result of `makeGameData ` is being used. It might require a string instead of a react node?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the item you want to render 
(`gameTitleArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * gameTitleArray.length)]`)
 is an object and not a string